# Making an angular filter conditional

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using a text input to filter a list of items. I'd like to make it so when a particular variable is set, the list doesn't filter, regardless of what the text input is. Any advice on how I can accomplish this?

```
<a ng-repeat="set in data | filter: { value: search }" data-id="{{set.id}}" ng-mousedown="setBox(set)" ng-mouseover="setSelected(set, $event)" ng-bind-html="set.value | trustHTML"></a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionally apply filters with ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206062/conditionally-apply-filters-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: I guess it may be a duplicate... though I can't say I'm happy with the answer provided there :)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can achieve this if you set the filter expression to `''` (or `undefined`) - this causes the filter not to be applied - for when your `disableFilter` is set, or to the actual filter expression otherwise.

> **EDIT 2**:
>   The other answer (below by [@Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408220/968155)) is simpler and easier to understand. Can't remember now whether it didn't work for me initially or I simply didn't think of this simpler way.

So, assuming, this toggling variable - `disableFilter` - is a boolean :

```
<a ng-repeat="set in data | filter: (!disableFilter || '') && filterExpression">
```

(with `filterExpression` being whatever the expression you want to filter by). Your specific case would be:

```
<a ng-repeat="set in data | filter: (!disableFilter || '') && {value: search}">
```

**EDIT:**

To explain how the above works.

1. Remember that `||` and `&&` return the value of one of its operands.
2. `||` and `&&` use short-circuit evaluation - `true || (anything)` returns `true`; `false && (anything)` returns `false` - without evaluating the `(anything)` expression.
3. `''` is falsy (or use `undefined` instead, if it's clearer)

And so,

when `disableFilter === true`, `!disableFilter === false`, thus the second operand of `||` - the empty string `''` - is evaluated (it's falsy), and `(!disableFilter || '')` returns `''` - a falsy value, which short-circuits the `&&` operation and does not evaluate the second operand of `&&`. The return value of the expression is thus `''`.

when `disableFilter === false`, `!disableFilter === true`, which short-circuits the `||` operation, then the second operand of `&&` is evaluated and returned. The return value of the expression is thus `{value: search}`.

Read more about [logical operators here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: Awesome! This was the kind of thing I was trying to do! but I don't quite understand it, and hope you can expound. Isn't that saying if `disableFilter` is false or blank string? I don't understand how that equates.

Comment: That's fantastic! I completely neglected that in JS, logic between non-boolean values still evaluate as truey or falsy as you put it. I think the blank string, the falsy, is what threw me off.

Comment: not sure what i'm doing wrong but it doesn't work for me. when `!disableFilter` is true my filter weeds out all items in the list. I'm assuming I can pass a `scope.myFilterText` as the value in `{ value: myFilterText }`?

Comment: @chovy, if you removed the `(!disableFilter || '')` part, would it filter correctly?

Comment: @newdev `filter:filterText` works. `filter: {value: filterText}` does not

Comment: @chovy, ah... you just have different objects than the OP. In this question, the OP wants to filter by the `value` property of each object in iteration. In your case, just substitue `{value: filterText}` with whatever filter expression you would have used otherwise, e.g. `filter: (!disableFilter || '') && filterText`

Comment: I just was going to reply with that: `filter:(isFiltering || '') && filterText` - thanks

Comment: can anyone help out how to use this for custom filter? suppose I have slice filter which takes index input.


filter: syntax don't work for cutom filter right? 

one thing I can do is put condition inside my custom filter which I don't want to do.

help awaited

Comment: @zps215, I suggest you ask a new question accurately describing your situtation

Comment: Used it with `limitTo` filter , but couldnt get it to work

Comment: There is a 3rd parameter in filter to do an exact match comparison (===) like `filter : {value:search} :true`. I don't know how to make this conditional filtering with that 3rd parameter! Any Idea?

Comment: Just found a way: `filter : (doFilter?{value:search}:'') :(doFilter?true:false)`

Comment: What is wrong with `disableFilter ? '' : filterExpression` ? Isn't it more readable?

Answer (score 54):

I think the following is a slightly less tricky solution. Tricky solutions cause bugs for future developers.

Here's my suggestion:

```
<a ng-repeat="set in data | filter: (shouldFilter ? filterExpression : '')">
```

or

```
<a ng-repeat="set in data | filter: (shouldFilter ? {value: search} : '')">
```

Simply, if shouldFilter, then give it your filter expression, otherwise give it nothing. 
Using a simple ternary expression will be easier for readability.

Comment: Very simple and easy to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Definitely a simpler approach than mine.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe use an `ng-if`?

```
<a ng-if="!myConditional" ng-repeat="set in data" data-id="{{set.id}}" ng-mousedown="setBox(set)" ng-mouseover="setSelected(set, $event)" ng-bind-html="set.value | trustHTML"></a>
<a ng-if="myConditional" ng-repeat="set in data | filter: { value: search }" data-id="{{set.id}}" ng-mousedown="setBox(set)" ng-mouseover="setSelected(set, $event)" ng-bind-html="set.value | trustHTML"></a>
```

That seems to be the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206062/conditionally-apply-filters-with-ng-repeat).

Comment: It's work, but if we want to know the array's length (For infinite scroll), we can't ... :/

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did. First, I had a select control, populated from my controller, with one static item (Select...) with a zero length string value:

```
<select data-ng-model="districtFilter" class="form-control" data-ng-options="d.DistrictId as d.DistrictName for d in districts | orderBy: 'DistrictName'"><option value="">Select...</option></select>
```

Then I applied the filter conditionally on the table. It appears when the filter is null, setting it to undefined clears it:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="courtEntity in courts | filter:{ 'DistrictId' : districtFilter === null ? undefined : districtFilter}">
```

Comment: I just use terneary as <tr data-ng-repeat="courtEntity in courts | filter:(districtFilter === null )? undefined : districtFilter}">.

Answer (score 0):

I had a complicated case

- Have a list of records say it products
- Filter by two other property `prop1`, `prop2` selected by user from drop down
- Another dropdown (`prop3`) have two value 1 and 2, if user select 2 filter should not be applied

Hers is my outcome:

```
ng-repeat="prod in filterdProd = 
 (products | filter : model.prop3 == 2 ? '' :  
   { 'prop1': model.prop1 || 'none', 
     'prop2': model.prop2 }) | 
  orderBy: 'productrName'"
```

if `model.prop3 == 2 ? ''` filter will not apply otherwise ...

We can also use the count of records by using filterdProd

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution more easy and effective

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.package=[{"PkgServiceId":null,"PkgServicesName":" HB, TLC, DLC &amp; ESR, EDTA WHOLE BLOOD, HBSAG CONFIRMATION,SERUM, Blood Cholesterol","PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":5,"ServiceDesc":null,"ServiceId":108,"ServiceName":"Family Health Package"},{"PkgServiceId":108,"PkgServicesName":null,"PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":5,"ServiceDesc":null,"ServiceId":70,"ServiceName":"HB, TLC, DLC & ESR, EDTA WHOLE BLOOD"},{"PkgServiceId":108,"PkgServicesName":null,"PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":5,"ServiceDesc":null,"ServiceId":71,"ServiceName":"HBSAG CONFIRMATION,SERUM"},{"PkgServiceId":108,"PkgServicesName":null,"PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":3,"ServiceDesc":"Its used to evaluate your overall health and detect a wide range of disorders","ServiceId":2,"ServiceName":"Blood Cholesterol"},{"PkgServiceId":null,"PkgServicesName":" MRI Test, HB, TLC &amp; DLC, EDTA WHOLE BLOOD","PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":5,"ServiceDesc":null,"ServiceId":107,"ServiceName":"Child Health Package"},{"PkgServiceId":107,"PkgServicesName":null,"PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":5,"ServiceDesc":"Its used to evaluate your overall health and detect a wide range of disorders","ServiceId":5,"ServiceName":"MRI Test"},{"PkgServiceId":107,"PkgServicesName":null,"PromoDiscount":null,"PromoID":null,"ReportPeriod":5,"ServiceDesc":null,"ServiceId":69,"ServiceName":"HB, TLC & DLC, EDTA WHOLE BLOOD"}] ;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in package">
        {{ x.ServiceName }}
        
      </li>
    </ul>
<p>Above is the total data set without filtering.</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in package| filter :{PkgServiceId: null}">
    {{ x.ServiceName }}
    {{ x.PkgServiceId }}
    
  </li>
</ul>

</div>



<p>This example displays only the packages containing the packageId "null".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML Template Binding**

```
{{ dataX | date: expression ? 'dd/MM' : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make functions and combine with filterExpression.

Example I have a students list as below:

```
$scope.students = [  
   { name: 'Hai', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },  
   { name: 'Hai', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },  
   { name: 'Ho', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },  
   { name: 'Hoan', age: 40, gender: 'girl' },  
   { name: 'Hieu', age: 25, gender: 'boy' }  
 ];
```

I want to filter students via gender to be boy and filter by name of them.

The first I create a function named "filterbyboy" as following:

```
$scope.filterbyboy = function (genderstr) {  
   if ((typeof $scope.search === 'undefined')||($scope.search === ''))  
     return (genderstr = "")  
   else  
    return (genderstr = "boy");  
 };
```

Explaination: if not filter name then display all students else filter by input name and gender as 'boy'

Here is a demo [How to use and operator in AngularJs example](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/10/filter-by-and-operator-in-angularjs.html)