# AngularJS ng-repeat and toggle filter on/off?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I do not know how to write this filter expression.

I have an array of documents:

```
[{title: 'doc1', read: false}
{title: 'doc2', read: false}
{title: 'doc3', read: false}
{title: 'doc4', read: true}
{title: 'doc5', read: false}]
```

On the view I have

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterRead">
<div ng-repeat="doc in documents track by $index | filter: ??? ">
   {{doc.title}}
</div>
```

If the checkbox/filterRead is true, assign no filter and show all the documents. If the checkbox is false, only show the documents where doc.read=false. I do not know how to write this filter expression elegantly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an angular filter conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional)

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, you don't need a filter, you could use an ng-if:

Controller: (or if you want have the logic straight in the HTML)

```
$scope.showDoc = function () {
    return $scope.filterRead || !doc.read;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="doc in documents track by $index" ng-if="showDoc()">
   {{doc.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it in template only. Here is an example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterRead.read" ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="'!null'">
<div ng-repeat="doc in documents | filter:filterRead track by $index ">
    {{doc.title}}
</div>
```

`ngFalseValue` directive does the trick here. When checkbox is not selected the model `filterRead.read` is set to something which is not equal to both `read` true or false. So as the result all records are rendered.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GO9vAZI3ghZuFb2eqa6h?p=preview