# AngularJS - stuck on removing/clearing a filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a filter applied on a drop down, but I would like it removed depending on another drop down value. Code below. If the user chooses "Medium" (or any other value), then I need the filter removed that gets applied when the user selects "Small". Right now, if the user chooses "Small" and then "Medium", the options are still being filtered out.

```
if(val == "Small"){
 $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options = $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options.filter(function(item) {
  return item.Value !== 'Red' && item.Value !== 'Blue';
 });
}
else if(val == "Medium") {
 $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options = $scope.Variant.Specs.Color.Options;
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional I didn't know the reply to your question, but that looks like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an angular $filter which takes the colors and size as arguments.

```
app.filter('filterColors', function() {
    return function(colors, size) {
        if(size=='Medium') {
            return colors;
        } else {
            return colors.filter(function(d) {
                return d != 'Red' && d != 'Blue';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lLuHBlpRXAS3UeCH9mFC?p=preview)