# Pass index to custom orderBy function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

This might be simple and stupid but I can't seem to figure it out. I have created a ng-repeat structure that I use multiple times on different objects. Basically, I iterate through elements in an array inside those objects and depending on some variable I either need to apply custom orderBy, or leave it in the original order.

So I've created that custom orderBy like that:

```
<li ng-repeat="tag in filter.tags | orderBy: customSort(filter.customSort)">
```

Basically, filter object contains array of tags and a boolean variable that states if custom sort needs to be applied. Within my customSort function I check if passed on parameter is true and perform that custom sort. But if it's false - I cannot seem to be able to output tags in their original order in that array.

I cannot pass **$index** because at that point it is always 0, it only becomes index inside that ng-repeat tag. I cannot do something like that **filter.tags.indexOf(tag)** because tag doesn't exist yet.

I'm kinda stuck, is there a way to apply orderBy conditionally?

Further explaination:
I iterate over an array of tags and print their localized values, some of those tags should be in their original order, some should be ordered alphabetically in their localized version. So my stripped custom sort does something like this:

```
$scope.customSort = function(language) {          
    return function(tag) {
        return $scope.tags.[language][tag];
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't need the function. Show some sample data and a value for `filter.customSort` and what `customSort()` does. Not entirely clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Added more details at the end of the question.

Comment: @pokrishka [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional) should help.

Comment: Just pass $index to the function $scope.customSort = function(language, $index), and return it if the other one is false.

Comment: @Vidul great, this seems to be what I need. Will give it a shot tomorrow, for some reason I didn't run into this thread when googling yesterday for almost exact same title.

Comment: @Vidul it doesn't work. Seems like that will only fit for filter where the result is true or false (match/mismatch), while orderBy returns the weight of each entry so they are sorted by this weight, in this case the result of the method you linked at is the same as if my customSort returned the same value for each entry (any value).

Comment: @OriDrori could you please suggest how do I pass index to the function? I've mentioned in my question that I tried that and couldn't. If I pass it on like orderBy: customSort($index) it would always be 0 inside customSort function.

Comment: Sorry - my bad. It seems that $index depends on orderBy, so you can pass it into an orderBy function. It seems that the indexOf method is the only one that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is the only solution I came up with, I will wait a little to see if anyone answers with a better one before I mark this one as correct.

I had to pass the entire array to the sorting function, along with boolean variable used to determine whether original order or custom sort is desired and then used indexOf like this:

```
$scope.customSort = function(perform, tags, language) {
    return function(tag) {
        if (!perform) return tags.indexOf(tag);       
        return $scope.tags.[language][tag];
    }
}
```