# conditionally apply angualrjs custom filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to call custom filter based on input in my template with ng-repeat.
so if myCondition is true then only I want to apply my custom filter slice otherwise I don't want to apply slice filter.

```
        <div ng-repeat = "job in userjobs.matched_jobs | slice:'5' && myCondition">
            <div ng-include="'applydiv.html'"></div>
        </div>
```

above code is not working as slice filter is getting true in input(5&&myCondition)

I can do hack here that

```
    <div ng-if="!myCondition">
        <div ng-repeat = "job in userjobs.matched_jobs">
            <div ng-include="'applydiv.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-else>
        <div ng-repeat = "job in userjobs.matched_jobs | slice:'5'">
            <div ng-include="'applydiv.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But then it will not follow DRY principle!
I have referred question at [Making an angular filter conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional)
but I can not use syntax filter:myCustomFilter in template so I need some another workaround.

Help required.

Comment: You could add the `myCondition` logic inside your filter instead.  For example, your could turn the filter argument into a function that uses that condition.

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes you can say it's one of the hack which I don't want to do as it will affect others using this filter.

thank for reply.

Comment: Ok yeah.  I don't have any ideas.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have full control of the filter code, you could always have a parameter to effectively disable the filter. Not to affect others, make it the last and optional parameter:

```
app.filter("slice", function(){
  return function(input, number, disable){
    if (disable) return input;

    // the rest of your filter
  }
})
```

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | slice:'5':!myCondition">
```

Alternatively, if you want to follow the [example of disabling the built-in filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740044/968155), you can make it so the filter is disabled if the first (and only, in this case) parameter is `undefined`:

```
app.filter("slice", function(){
  return function(input, number){
    if (!angular.isDefined(number)) return input;

    // the rest of your filter
  }
})
```

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | slice: (!myCondition || undefined) && '5'">
```