# OR logic on builtin filters in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
{HospitalName: "hospital name", DoctorDetails: {Name: "doctor name"}}
```

I am using ng-repeat to iterate over a list of such objects. At the same time, I am applying two filters with an OR logic such that at least one of them should be return a match(if any).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search by hospital or doctor name">

<div  ng-repeat="hospital in list | filter: {HospitalName : searchQuery} || {DoctorDetails : {Name : searchQuery}}">
    <div>{{hospital.HospitalName}}</div>
</div>
```

However, only the first filter gets triggered. Even though there are objects that have doctor names that match the search query, no matches are returned. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

I was using this post as reference for the conditional logic on the filter: [Making an Angular Filter Conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional)

**UPDATE:**

I was not able to figure out why the conditional logic was not working. So, taking @Walfrat's advice,I had to resort to using a custom filter and it gets the job done. If anyone is interested, here is the code I used:

```
angular.module('TestApp')
.filter('searchBox', function($filter, $rootScope) {
    return function(input, searchParam) {
        if(input) {
            var searchResults = null;
            //check if a valid search query has been entered
            if(searchParam){
                //use $filter to find hospital names that match query 
                searchResults = $filter('filter')(input,{HospitalName: searchParam});

                //if no hospital names match, fill searchResults with doctor name results(if any) that match query
                //otherwise just append the results to searchResults
                if(searchResults.length == 0){
                  searchResults = $filter('filter')(input,{DoctorDetails : {Name: searchParam}});
                }
                else{
                  angular.forEach($filter('filter')(input,{DoctorDetails : {Name: searchParam}}), function(result){
                    searchResults.push(result);
                  });
                }
                //if there are no doctor or hospital names that match,
                // set searchResult to approprriate message to denote no results found
                if(searchResults.length == 0){
                  searchResults = ["Nothing"];
                }
                return searchResults;
            }
            //console.log(out);
            return input;
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

For more concise code, see @Alex Chance's answer. Cheers!

Comment: 1st you're missing parenthesis around {HospitalName,...DoctorDetails...} to match exactly the answer provided in your link. Second i don't think that builtin angular filter works in angularJS. Just implements your own filter.

Comment: @Walfrat There doesn't seem to be any additional parenthesis around {Hospital Name,..DoctorDetails...}, there is only parenthesis around the expression in ng-repeat which I have maintained.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo You are saying that null || {name: 'test'} will return {name: 'test'}? If that is the case, then that is precisely the behaviour that I require. However, I am getting no matches at all.

Comment: Read the answer of the link you provided. On the filter: there is parenthesis around the expression, this might be necessary. And can you try with only  the DoctorDetails part ?I think angular builtin filter doesn't work with deep objects.

Comment: What Walfrat said is with you could to use only one parameter: ng-repeat="hospital in list | filter: {HospitalName : searchQuery, DoctorDetails : {Name : searchQuery}}, but I believe filter not will to search at second level.

Comment: @Walfrat Sorry about that, I missed the trailing parenthesis when copying the code. I have edited my post to reflect that. My original code has it and so that is not issue. And deep object searching works as I tested each of the expressions separately. Just the conditional logic is not working as expected.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I have tried using the expression you wrote, but then the {HospitalName : searchQuery, DoctorDetails : {Name : searchQuery}} is treated as a single object and a sort of AND logic operates as only queries which match both hospital and doctor name are shown. That is my understanding of it. I don't think there is any issue with searching at the second level, as I having tested with using the doctor name expression separately and it has worked.

Comment: I don't think that code will do what you think it will as it is meaningless without the 'filter: ' prefix. I tried the code, it simple assigns searchQuery to the first expression and logs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, it may be easier to apply a custom filter function.

You apply the filter in your ng-repeat like so

```
 <div  ng-repeat="hospital in list | filter:filterFn ">
```

The filter function would look like this:

```
   $scope.filterFn = function(hospital)
    {
           return hospital.HospitalName.search($scope.searchQuery) != -1 || 
           hospital.DoctorDetails.Name.search($scope.searchQuery) != -1;
    }
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfvbajz2/).

Comment: Thank you. I finally took @Walfrat 's advice and made a custom filter and it does the job. But your code should do the trick too. However, the fiddle you provided is something to do with todo lists and seems out of context. Please check.

Comment: I updated the link, sorry I had a few fiddles open at the same time and copied the wrong link. Glad you were able to find a solution.

Comment: That's ok. I am marking your answer as correct in case someone else faces the same problem. Cheers!