# Angular ng-repeat multiple filter OR

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I filter on `ng-repeat` with multiple filters on `OR`?

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter: searchText | filter: functionFilter" >
...
</div>
```

I want that `searchText` filter with all fields and it do that, with `functionFilter` I want check other things and it do that, but I want these two filters working with logial `OR` but now they are working with `AND`.

As suggested, I tried

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter: functionFilter || {value: searchText}" >
...
</div>
```

but it seems that works only `functionFilter` and also

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter: functionFilter ? '' : searchText" >
...
</div>
```

simply show all.

Comment: Try with: `filter: searchText || functionFilter`

Comment: @PrerakSola, like that works only `searchText`

Comment: What is `functionFilter`? Is it a custom filter?

Comment: Is just a function that return `true` or `false` under certain condition

Comment: i think you can try it by writing single filter and do the both filter operation in single filter

Comment: Ok, it was my first option but I want to know if there is a way to concatenate more filters with logic `OR`

Comment: Check this out "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional?answertab=active#tab-top"

Comment: @Amit udated question, in fact it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Make a common function for this. Here it is `searchText`

**Inside HTML...**

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter: searchText >
...
</div>
```

**Inside Controlller...**

*I made the dummy example. You have to manage condition according to you.*

```
$scope.searchText = function(item) {
    if (!$scope.query || (item.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query) != -1) || (item.model.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query.toLowerCase()) != -1) ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Yes, as I commented above, this is my first option, but I want to know if there is a way to concatenate more filters with logic `OR`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use `||` operator between 2 filters.

I have create a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitGoda/uwb2s9tb/2/) to test the scenario.

Notice that

- Initially the filter is by default applied by `filterFunction` and `searchText` both.
- The moment you change the `seachText` value to `"Harry"` it shows only that result.
- If the input box is cleared, than only `filterFunction` filter is applied.

Comment: If I change `filerText` it not apply `filterFunction` so it is not a logical `OR`, it is something like: apply `filterFunction` if `filterText` is empty but I need to apply `filterFunction OR filterText` independent on each status

Comment: It would be good if you can provide an example with plunkr or fiddle and demonstrate what exactly is required.

Comment: i updated your https://jsfiddle.net/uwb2s9tb/3/ as you can see, I want to filter this, for example, with value `"t"` I need to maintain item `101` because in his name has a `"t"` and also item `102` because `functionFilter` return `true` and also his name has "`t`", instead I have only the second element (only the function will be applied)

your example works only because the function filter like the normal filter, value `"101"` is checked on every field by default filter