# Angularjs Filter On Object Property If Object Not Null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do the following:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="user in ctr.users | filter:{entity.name:filterEntityName}" >
```

...however, some of the users have null entities. How can I filter on the entity name only when the entity exists?

Comment: You can write a custom filter function. Please see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter - search for "create custom filters". In the custom function, you can check if entity exists and then apply the filter.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738014/making-an-angular-filter-conditional) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is custom filter with arbitrary length of property chain(`entity.name.data`). If some property value is falsy(`!val`), item goes to output, otherwise it happens only if target value contains search goal(`val.indexOf(value) != -1`):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    this.users = [
      {entity:{name:{data:'Max'}}, name: 'Max'},      
      {entity:{name:{data:'Sam'}}, name: 'Sam'},
      {name: 'Henry'},
      {entity: null, name: 'John'},                  
      {entity: {name:null}, name: 'Kate'},                  
      {entity: {name:{data:null}}, name: 'Tom'},             
    ]
}).filter('myfilter', function(){
  return function(array, search){
    var property = Object.keys(search)[0];
    var value = search[property];
    if(value){      
      var props = property.split('.');
      return array.filter(x => {        
        for(var prop of props){
          var index = props.indexOf(prop);
          var last = props.length - 1;
          
          val = index == 0 ? x[prop] : val[prop];                    
          if(!val)
            return true;
          if(val && index == last)
            return val.indexOf(value) != -1;                    
        }        
      });
    }
    return array;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl as ctr'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='filterEntityName'/>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="user in ctr.users | myfilter:{entity.name.data:filterEntityName}">
    {{user | json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use '!!' in filters to skip if property is undefined or null.

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="user in ctr.users | filter:{entity.name: '!!'}" >
```