# ngRepeat and filtering list based on collection value

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is an example of my data that I run through my `ng-repeat`.  Is it possible to run it through ngRepeat but only where `lineNum >= 1` and `lineNum <= 10` within the HTML? I could do it with creating separate variables and using another plugin like linq.js but was hoping to avoid that.

```
{
    "00100":{ lineNum: 1.00, Columns: {..} }
    "00200":{ lineNum: 2.00, Columns: {..} }
    "02000":{ lineNum: 20.00, Columns: {..} }
    "20000":{ lineNum: 200.00, Columns: {..} }
}
```

Comment: What kind of data is that? Neither it is an object nor an array?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Sorry, updated the data

Comment: you can use the `filter` for accomplish this. an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206062/conditionally-apply-filters-with-ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use an `ng-if` on the `ngRepeat` element. I'm also assuming your data has a syntax error and assume it looks like:

```
$scope.myData = {
    "00100":{ lineNum: 1.00, Columns: {..} }
    "00200":{ lineNum: 2.00, Columns: {..} }
    "02000":{ lineNum: 20.00, Columns: {..} }
    "20000":{ lineNum: 200.00, Columns: {..} }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData" ng-if="value.lineNum > 1 && value.lineNum < 10">
    {{key}}
</div>
```

Comment: isn't there a lot of overhead in this?  This was just a small sample of data (I updated my original data, I did have syntax error).  I'm not opposed to writing a custom filter, I just didn't want to have multiple variables that I split the collection in when then controller loads

Comment: @collinszac10 -- You're not splitting the collection at all - if anything there's less overhead. `ngIf` won't even append the content to the DOM if the condition isn't met.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what kind of data is yours but with a list of data like:

```
var records = {
    lineNum: 1.00, Columns: {..},
    lineNum: 2.00, Columns: {..},
    lineNum: 20.00, Columns: {..},
    lineNum: 200.00, Columns: {..},
};
```

You can write like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records" ng-if="record.lineNum >= 1 && record.lineNum <= 10">{{record.lineNum}}
</div>
```

It's a workaround since you want to do in the HTML itself.

Comment: Gotta use the object repeat syntax: `(k, v) in obj`

Comment: Yup, I explained based on the example :) Will update that and probably, I'll delete my answer since yours & mine will become same :-)